# Xwayland and Wayland -- best way to set enviromental variables

Tags: xorg, environment-variables, wayland

I am on Debian 11 and I am using Sway awhich is an Wlroot Wayland compositor.

I set up Sway to automatically open on each login *(only from from within terminal `/dev/tty1`)*:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/1
  └─> cat .bash_profile 
    
# Only /dev/tty1 can open sway
if [ "$(tty)" = "/dev/tty1" ]; then
        exec sway
fi
```

I also set up enviromental variables that make sure **all** applications use Wayland backend (`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland`) and not Xorg (`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb`):

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/1
  └─> cat /etc/environment

export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct

export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
# export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb

export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
```

This means that **all** applications that only know Xorg will fail to start because they try to use Wayland backend!

### My solution:

In order for them to work we have to first install the Xwayland:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/1
  └─> sudo apt install xwayland
```

But after this, Xorg applications will still try to use Wayland and will still fail.

In my case I make Xorg applications work if I export enviromental variables just before I execute the applications. This is the example:

```
env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb DISPLAY=:0 freecad
```

**Note:** Xorg uses different display labeling (`DISPLAY=:0`) than Wayland (`WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0`) so if we insist that application should use Xorg backend, we also make sure we provide a display for the backend. Otherwise this would fail.

### The problem:

While this solution works it is hard to keep up with all the Xorg applications. For example...

I installed the native `kicad` package and Kicad does not support Wayland. So I have to manually **move it's executable file** from `/usr/bin/kicad` to `/usr/bin/kicad.bin`:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> sudo mv /usr/bin/kicad /usr/bin/kicad.bin
```

And **substitute the executable file with the script** `/usr/bin/kicad` that sets the needed enviromental variables before executing the **moved executable file** i.e. `/usr/bin/kicad.bin`:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> sudo touch /usr/bin/kicad

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > Downloads
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/kicad

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/1
  └─> cat /usr/bin/kicad
#!/bin/bash
env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb DISPLAY=:0 kicad.bin
```

This takes a lot of time and I have to repeat it each time I reinstall the packages! It is a horrible solution. So is there any other solution?

I read somewhere that it is possible to not set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` and leave applications to set it by themselves. What would I have to change?

Comment: I found out that if I export either `DISPLAY=:0` or `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0` inside `/etc/environment` my desktop manager i.e. `sway` will not start, because it probably needs to export these variables but can't as they already exist. So I started playing with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` that takes values `xcb`, `wayland`, `wayland;xcb`, `xcb;wayland`. Later runs applications with **X** backend first and in case of failure it tries **Wayland** backend. I found out that when I use this one, my display manager i..e `sway` will also export both `DISPLAY=:0` **and** `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0`.

Comment: It looks like now I can run any program without writing bash scripts for it... I am just unsure if now most of my applications are using X backend i.e. `xwayland`. I am not sure, if this is the "fastest" solution, but it surely makes life easier on me.

Comment: [Here](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2018/03/unsetting-qt_qpa_platform-environment-variable-by-default/) is also some introspection.

Comment: This works for native Debian applications, but will fail on flatpaks, where we can just export enviromental varriables, like I already pointed out. It is crutial for me that now at least native distribution's packages run! Flatpaks are and should be treated as an exception. The solution is probably if flatpak packagers remove QT from their packages so that package needs to use native QT!

Comment: I was wrong. This "solution" does not work for all the native applications.